# How to submit an attchment with POST request body in SOAP UI

Tags: soapui

I need to send a POST Rest request with multiple file attachment with a request SOAP body. While sending I need to provide a variable name for request body and another variable name for my attachments.

Ex:

userinfo  --> contains below request body

{
"firstNm": "",
"lastNm": "",
}

userfiles  --> Contains more than one attachment. This I can achive using attachment section. How to give a name for POST request body.

Comment: How would the actual POST call be made?  Would it use a multipart form, or something else?

Comment: Its mutipartform is there any other ways when we have attachments?